# How do I deploy a MERN application on a godaddy VPS

Tags: node.js, web-deployment, vps, mern

The only experience I have with deploying something is via git onto Heroku. How do I deploy an entire website onto a go daddy VPS?

I downloaded puTTY(SSH) and was able to connect to the server, from there I installed nvm and it's now allowing me to use node and NPM. If I use the ls command from the bash terminal it doesn't show any files. How do I actually upload my project onto the server and have them displayed on the website?

doing it with git and Heroku was easy I just created a Heroku link, logged in and pushed my application with GIT.

I'd like to deploy a basic MERN website to a GoDaddy VPS and have it displayed on the intended domain.

Comment: Any updates on this? If you got the way then please update it into an answer. Thanks

Comment: @JustCurious ah I vaguely remember this was over a year ago. I did end up getting it deployed but I couldn't tell you how off the top of my head. Sorry, wish I could provide more help.